# Check if RichTextBox has formatting (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

Is there a way to detect if there is formatting or not (i.e. Rich) anywhere in a RichTextBox?

I'd like to write RichTextBox.Rtf is there is, and RichTextBox.Text if there isn't.

I came across a post that suggested checking the SelectionFont after selecting all text, but I have no idea how to accomplish that, or if it would work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the rtf property of the richtextbox: `richtextbox1.rtf`to see the rich text code. Even with no additional formatting, there will be some  rich text formatting. For example, here's what you get with a richtextbox containing only "text":

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 test\par
}
```

You can check to see if there are any additional formatting tags, and if not, it should be plain text. You can also access the plain text (without formatting) with `richtextbox1.text`.